# Lua string append function size versus hard-coded string

Tags: string, memory, lua, append, byte

I call `string.len` on `"\005\033\011\045"` it `returns 4`

whereas if I create a string like,

```
str = "\005" .. "\033" .. "\011" .. "\045"
```

and do `string.len(str)` it `returns 16`

forgive me if my code is not complete

Comment: both give me 4, in 5.1,5.2, and 5.3. what version of lua are you running?

Comment: I'm using online editor: https://repl.it/~, which is saying it's version 5.1.5

Comment: got the 4 from both in https://repl.it/languages/lua as well. can you add your exact code to the question

Comment: print( string.len("\001\002\003\004\005"))
=5

str = "\001" .. "\002" .. "\003"  .. "\004" .. "\00" .. "5"
print(string.len(str))
=6

Comment: print( string.len("\001\002\003\004\005"))
=5
    /////    
str = "\001" .. "\002" .. "\003"  .. "\004" .. "\00" .. "5"
/////   print(string.len(str))
=6

Comment: you cant expect `"\00" .. "5"` to end up as `"\005"` the char for `\00`is created and then you are appending the char for "5" next to it. basically  your making `NULL5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both strings have a length of 4:

```
str = "\005\033\011\045"

str_concat = "\005" .. "\033" .. "\011" .. "\045"

print(string.len(str), string.len(str_concat))
```

If you are try to dynamically create a char, as would be indicated by some information you provided in the comments you need to do it like this:

```
str_concat = "\005" .. "\033" .. "\011" .. string.char(45) -- note string.char excepts a number value.
```

Comment: That is very helpful, and looks like it will solve my issue, thank you very much!

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as solved, so other people don't try to answer it.